# How to convert values into array of object?

Tags: php, arrays

I have following values,

```
firstsession
secondsession
thirdsession
B+
```

i have to convert the above to values to array of object,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Itemname] => firstsession
    [Ability] => B+
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Itemname] => secondsession
    [Ability] => B+
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Itemname] => thirdsession
    [Ability] => B+
)
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small class

```
<?php

    class Item {
        public $Itemname;
        public $Ability;

        public function __construct($name,$ability) {
            $this->Itemname = $name;
            $this->Ability = $ability;
        }
    }

    $arr = array(
        new Item('firstsession','B+'),
        new Item('secondsession','B+'),
        new Item('thirdsession','B+'),
    );

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking for...
http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/

Quick g search, though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();

$a = new stdClass;
$a->Itemname = "first session";
$a->Ability = "B+";

$b = new stdClass;
$b->Itemname = "second session";
$b->Ability = "B+";

$c = new stdClass;
$c->Itemname = "third session";
$c->Ability = "B+";

$arr[] = $a;
$arr[] = $b;
$arr[] = $c;
```

like this?

Comment: You're dealing with plain arrays here. Either you cast your items to objects or you're not achieving what question asks.

Comment: ok i've edited my answer. if this doesn't answer the question, it means i didn't get the question. by the way castng an array as stdClass will return an empty object and you will lose the keys and the cursor.